# Boolean indexing in Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['n1', 'n1', 'n2', 'n2'], ['p', 'm', 'p', 'm']])
values = [
    [1,      2,  3,      4],
    [np.nan, 6,  7,      8],
    [np.nan, 10, np.nan, 12],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
```

```
    n1       n2    
     p   m    p   m
0  1.0   2  3.0   4
1  NaN   6  7.0   8
2  NaN  10  NaN  12
```

Now I want to set `m` to `NaN` whenever `p` is `NaN`. Here's the result I'm looking for:

```
    n1        n2     
     p    m    p    m
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I know how to find out where `p` is `NaN`, for example using

```
mask = df.xs('p', level=1, axis=1).isnull()
```

```
      n1     n2
0  False  False
1   True  False
2   True   True
```

However, I don't know how to use this mask to set the corresponding `m` values in `df` to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to obtain a boolean ndarray indicating whether values are `NaN` or not in the `p` column on level `1` and then replacing `False` to `NaN`, and also to replace the values in `m` by multiplying the result:

```
x = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'p']].notna().replace({False:float('nan')}).values
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'m']] *= x

       n1        n2     
     p    m    p    m
0  1.0    2  3.0    4
1  NaN  NaN  7.0    8
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stack and unstack the transposed dataframe to be able to easily select and change values, and then again stack, unstack and transpose to get it back:

```
df = df.T.stack(dropna=False).unstack(level=1)
df.loc[df['p'].isna(), 'm'] = np.nan

df = df.stack(dropna=False).unstack(1).T
```

---

After first line, `df` is:

```
         m    p
n1 0   2.0  1.0
   1   6.0  NaN
   2  10.0  NaN
n2 0   4.0  3.0
   1   8.0  7.0
   2  12.0  NaN
```

And after last:

```
    n1        n2     
     m    p    m    p
0  2.0  1.0  4.0  3.0
1  NaN  NaN  8.0  7.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This works, but note that the `stack` / `unstack` combo sorts the columns which might not be desirable.